# How to read in multiple .csv files in R through a if for statement?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, read.csv

I have many .csv files labeled by year. i.e.

```
2017TMAXMIN.csv
2016TMAXMIN.csv
2015TMAXMIN.csv
2014TMAXMIN.csv
.
.
.
```

And so on going back about 40 years.

I am attempting to read in these .csv files based on user input date. For example, the user may specify they would file from 2016 and 2017 based on the user input.

Below is the code I have so far.

```
setwd("P:/%%%%%%/FTP_Yearly_Climate_Data")
FromDate <- "20170115" #enter from date in YYYYMMDD format
ToDate <- "20161215" #enter to date in YYYYMMDD format
AnalysisType <- "maxtemp" #maxtemp, mintemp, precip

filename <- "TMAXMIN.csv"
FromYear <- as.numeric(substr(FromDate, 1, 4))
ToYear <- as.numeric(substr(ToDate, 1, 4))

if (FromYear != ToYear) {
  for (i in ToYear:FromYear) {
    i <- paste0(i, sub('\\..*', '', filename), '.csv')
    read.csv(i, header=TRUE, sep=",")
    print(i)
  }
}
```

When I run this code, nothing imports; however, I do get a value of `i` labeled `2017TMAXMIN.csv`. Ideally, I would like the two years to import. When the `print(i)` runs in the if/for loop, the output is below.

```
[1] "2016TMAXMIN.csv"
[1] "2017TMAXMIN.csv"
```

I am pretty new to R (coding in general), so any advice or help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You need to assign the `read.csv` statement to a variable if you wish to "import" it into R environment. I.e. before `for` loop - get headers (or manually define them) in a variable e.g. `df <- data.frame(x = numeric())` and then within loop `df <- rbind(df, read.csv(...))`.

Comment: It is not advisable to modify the loop index inside the loop , `i` in your case and any other name such as  `fileName` should work fine i.e. `fileName <- paste0(i, sub('\\..*', '', filename), '.csv');read.csv(fileName, header=TRUE, sep=",")`